# Are All Nonstandard Models of PA Ill-Founded?

Tags: set-theory, peano-axioms

We often use sets to represent natural numbers, but we can also use natural numbers to represent sets. For example, we can use the binary expansion of a natural number to represent a set. The number seven (111 base 2) could represent the set {2,1,0}.

It is known [Peano Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) (PA) is bi-interpretable with ZF - Infinity + all sets are finite + all sets have a transitive closure (ZF-Inf+TC). See [Kang and Wong: On Interpretations of Arithmetic and Set Theory](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1193667707).

The [axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists) is an axiom of ZF-Inf+TC and it says there are no infinite descending chains of nested sets. Assume we have a nonstandard model of PA. Let $x$ be a nonstandard natural number larger than any standard natural number. Consider the sets defined by 
$2^x-1, 2^{x-1}-1, 2^{x-2}-1, ..., 2^0-1$.

This seems to be an infinite descending chain of nested sets.

My question is whether PA has ill-founded models and if so, how can it be bi-interpretable with ZF-Inf+TC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is easy to show that, too.

Suppose that $M$ is a model of Peano and its $\leq^M$ order is well-ordered (equivalently, well-founded). Consider $N\subseteq M$ the set made of $0^M$ and closed under $S^M$ (this is the interpretation of all the numerals in $M$).

If $M\setminus N$ is non-empty it has a least element $m$, but $m\neq 0^M$, therefore $m=S^M(x)$ for some $x\in N$. This is a contradiction since if $x\in N$ we have that $S^M(x)\in N$ too.

Do note that the definition of $N$ is external to $M$. But then again the definition of "non-standard" is external too.

You can show, however that if $A\subseteq M$ is a [parameter-free] definable set, then it is empty, or has a minimal element. It goes on to show that $N$ itself is not definable without parameters.

---

As for being bi-interpretable with $\sf ZF-Inf+TC$, note that the axiom of regularity is internal, not external. It is perfectly fine that $\sf ZF$ has an ill-founded model, as long as the model "doesn't know" about the decreasing chain.

Namely, every set **inside** the model, has a $\in$-minimal element. But it doesn't mean that every subset of the model is a set in the model.

Perhaps something which is worth pointing out, both $\sf ZF$ and $\sf PA$ are first-order theories. They have very limited powers when it comes to talking about sub-collections of the universe. Both can only ensure that a small fragments of these have a minimal element. So we can't quite write down the statement "Every set has a minimal element", and this fact exactly is what allows non-standard elements to exist.

Comment: "If M∖N is non-empty it has a least element m" may not be true. N could be the standard natural numbers.

Comment: Yes, so the only way there is no contradiction is $M\setminus N=\varnothing$ and therefore $M$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$, the standard model of $\sf PA$.

Comment: If N is the standard natural numbers then M\N is not empty and it doesn't have a least element.

Comment: You're jumping too fast for me. I'm sorry. We have $M$. Is it *any* model of $\sf PA$ or a non-standard model of $\sf PA$?

Comment: M/N being non-empty does not mean it has a least element $m$. M could be a nonstandard model and N the standard model. You only assume N is a subset of M, contains 0, and is closed under successor. The standard natural numbers satisfy this definition.

Comment: Russell, you completely misunderstood my answer, then. Let me explain it again. Take $M$ to be a model of $\sf PA$. It has an initial segment which is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$, by considering the interpretation of the numerals: terms which have the form $S\ldots S0$. Now, if $\leq^M$ is a well-order then either $M$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ or there is a least element $m$ which is not in that initial segment, which is a contradiction since this $m$ is not zero, therefore it is a successor for some $n$, but now $n$ is the interpretation of a numeral and therefore $m$ must be too.

Comment: If you disagree, please point out **exactly** what you disagree with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15367/discussion-between-russell-easterly-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: I have no intention of using the chat system. Feel free to continue with the comments, and ignore the automatic suggestion.

Comment: OK. If M\N is not empty and does not have a minimal element then it is not well ordered contradicting our assumption of well ordering.

Comment: Yes, precisely. (This was a homework assignment to my students a couple of weeks ago, by the way.)